# Jquery Validate custom error message location

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

This looks very simply, but I can't figure it out. I'm using the jquery validate plugin. I'm trying to validate `<input name=first>` and `<input name=second>` to output the error messages into:

```
<span id="errNm2"></span> <span id="errNm1"></span>
```

I already started writing the errorPlacement: which is where you customize your error message location.

How can I put the errors message in those `<span>`?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.append($('.errorTxt span'));
        },
        rules,
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="first"/>
<input type="text" name="second"/>

<div class="errorTxt">
   <span id="errNm2"></span>
   <span id="errNm1"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

What you should use is the [errorLabelContainer](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      first: {
        required: true
      },
      second: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {},
    errorElement : 'div',
    errorLabelContainer: '.errorTxt'
  });
});
```

```css
.errorTxt{
  border: 1px solid red;
  min-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="first" />
  <input type="text" name="second" />
  <div class="errorTxt"></div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---

If you want to retain your structure then

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var validator = $('#form').validate({
    rules: {
      first: {
        required: true
      },
      second: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {},
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      var placement = $(element).data('error');
      if (placement) {
        $(placement).append(error)
      } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#errNm1 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#errNm2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" name="first" data-error="#errNm1" />
  <input type="text" name="second" data-error="#errNm2" />
  <div class="errorTxt">
    <span id="errNm2"></span>
    <span id="errNm1"></span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I would suggest a small change in the code `$(placement).append(error)` ... here if the validation is triggered multiple times `(Eg: multiple submit button click)` then the error also gets appended multiple times. So I think its better to have `html` instead of `append` ... `$(placement).html(error)`

Answer (score 21):

You can simply create extra conditions which match the fields you require in the same function. For example, using your code above...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            //Custom position: first name
            if (element.attr("name") == "first" ) {
                $("#errNm1").text(error);
            }
            //Custom position: second name
            else if (element.attr("name") == "second" ) {
                $("#errNm2").text(error);
            }
            // Default position: if no match is met (other fields)
            else {
                 error.append($('.errorTxt span'));
            }
        },
        rules
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: this almost worked for me. The only problem I have is the 'else' condition. How do change it to run the default validation placement?

Comment: This works, but consider instead Arun's solution using data attributes to allow you to specify this in the markup and not have to add a new condition to the errorPlacement function for each input, which isn't very DRY.

Answer (score 4):

```
 if (e.attr("name") == "firstName" ) {
     $("#firstName__validate").text($(error).text());
     console.log($(error).html());
 }
```

Try this get text of error object

Answer (score 3):

Just add an empty label tag with the same id as input field has + "-error", for example.

```
<input id="myID1" required>
<input id="myID2" required>
<div>
    <label id="myID1-error" class="error" for="myID1"></label>
    <label id="myID2-error" class="error" for="myID2"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<form ... id ="GoogleMapsApiKeyForm">
    ...
    <input name="GoogleMapsAPIKey" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Google maps API key" />
    ....
    <span class="text-danger" id="GoogleMapsAPIKey-errorMsg"></span>'
    ...
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {
    $("#GoogleMapsApiKeyForm").validate({
      rules: {
          GoogleMapsAPIKey: {
              required: true
          }
        },
        messages: {
            GoogleMapsAPIKey: 'Google maps api key is required',
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "GoogleMapsAPIKey")
                $("#GoogleMapsAPIKey-errorMsg").html(error);
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
           // form.submit(); //if you need Ajax submit follow for rest of code below
        }
    });

    //If you want to use ajax
    $("#GoogleMapsApiKeyForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!$("#GoogleMapsApiKeyForm").valid())
            return;

       //Put your ajax call here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This Worked for me

Actually error is a array which contain error message and other values for elements we pass, you can console.log(error); and see.
Inside if condition "error.appendTo($(element).parents('div').find($('.errorEmail')));"
Is nothing but finding html element in code and passing the error message.

```
    $("form[name='contactUs']").validate({
rules: {
    message: 'required',
    name: "required",
    phone_number: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 10,
        number: false
    },
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    }
},
messages: {
    name: "Please enter your name",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address",
    message: "Please enter your message",
    phone_number: "Please enter a valid mobile number"
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $("#errorText").empty();

        if(error[0].htmlFor == 'name')
        {
            error.appendTo($(element).parents('div').find($('.errorName')));
        }
        if(error[0].htmlFor == 'email')
        {
            error.appendTo($(element).parents('div').find($('.errorEmail')));
        }
        if(error[0].htmlFor == 'phone_number')
        {
            error.appendTo($(element).parents('div').find($('.errorMobile')));
        }
        if(error[0].htmlFor == 'message')
        {
            error.appendTo($(element).parents('div').find($('.errorMessage')));
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your validate method:

```
 errorLabelContainer: '#errors'
```

and in your html, put simply this where you want to catch the error:

```
<div id="errors"></div>
```

All the errors will be held in the div, independently of your input box.

It worked very fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code with the jQuery validation logic to display the error message in a different place:

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#form').validate({
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    if (element.attr("name") == "policy_accepted") {
                        error.appendTo($('#policy_accepted_error'))
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                },
                errorClass: 'text-danger',
                rules: {
                    policy_accepted: {
                        required: true,
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                  policy_accepted: {
                        required: "You have to accept our terms & condition",
                    },
                } 
            });
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<form id="form" method="post">
<div class="mb-3">
  <label class="lg">
    <input type="checkbox" name="policy_accepted" class="form-check-input me-2" value="1" />
    <span>
        I agree to the <a href="">guest policies</a> ,
        <a href="">cancellation policy</a>, and the guest
        refund policy.
    </span>
  </label>
  <p class="text-danger" id="policy_accepted_error"></p>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="large-btn">Continue to Booking</button>
</form>
```